# SwiftUI: How to set gradient foreground color to multiple Text() in single view

Tags: text, swiftui, gradient, linear-gradients

I have `View` with multiple `Text()`.

If I apply gradient foreground colour to a single `Text()`, it works. But it doesn't works if apply the same for all `Text()`.

Maybe its masking issue. But couldn't found a way to achieve what I'm looking for.

I have below the extension method to apply a gradient.

```
extension View {
    public func gradientForeground(colors: [Color]) -> some View {
        self.overlay(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: colors),
                                    startPoint: .topLeading,
                                    endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
            .mask(self)
    }
}
```

Works fin:

```
var body: some View {
VStack {
    Text("SwiftUI ")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .blue])
    Text("is awesome")
        .font(.headline)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)

 }  
}
```

But doesn't work:

```
var body: some View {
VStack {
    Text("SwiftUI ")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .blue])
    Text("is awesome")
        .font(.headline)
        .gradientForeground(colors: [.red, .blue])

 }  
}
```

Comment: Would you show example of how do you want to use it with multiple Text/s?

Comment: Works fine with VStack of Text elements (at least same as with single one). Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.3 and iOS 14.3

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Could you add screenshot of what's wrong and what's expected?